# Automatize test build process with maven

Tags: java, maven, testing

We have a Java Web Project running on Tomcat 7 and we use Maven as our build tool. In our actual test process we need to do some manual steps to build our project for test environment:

1. Checkout git branch with the code to test.
2. With maven, use the production profile to create the war file running `mvn clean package -P production`.
3. Access our local PC where the war file will be deployed `http://192.168.0.105:8080/manager/html` using a web browser.
4. Upload the war file generated by maven and wait for deploy finishes.
5. Our tester start the testing
6. If any problem is found, we fix it and repeat the process until the test is successful

What we would like to achieve is a minimum manual process as possible, with for example running a command like `mvn deployTest -DtestId=SC-1550` will do the following steps:

1. Run unit tests
2. Run integration tests
3. Build the war file on production profile
4. Use the parameter "testId" as the war file name, so our tester will access `https://localhost:8443/TESTID` and start the testing. In that way, we can have multiple features ready for testing, just need to access the correct address with the test issue ID.
5. The war file is deployed to Tomcat 7 using the `maven-tomcat7` plugin in the specific IP address of our test machine
6. The environment is ready for testing with the new feature.
7. If any problem is found, we commit the fix on our git and again, run the maven command `mvn deployTest -DtestId=SC-1550`

Doing so, we substitute a mostly manual process to a single command, speeding up our testing.

My question is if there is a way to automatize this process by configuring the pom file, or using a plugin or even implementing our own plugin to do this steps with a single command.

---

Answering @avojak and updating question with a motivation:

We are a small startup with our product in early to mid stages. Only now we are focusing on test automation, so we have almost none of it, not even basic unit tests. For this reason, all of our tests are made in a exploratory way, skipping the unit and integration tests, until we implement it. Parallel to this, we are implementing Scrum with the JIRA tool. We established that there will be a step where our Product Owner will check if the feature works accordingly expected (the QA step), so that is why I would like to link the JIRA issue with war filename, where he can access our test server directly with id of the issue to be tested.

Comment: Your question is too broad, there are a LOT of ways to achieve what you describe with Maven and various other tools. Look aroung on any search engine you will have a lot of ressources. SO will be able to help you if you have a specific issue. You may want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You may check maven plugins such as [Arqullian](http://arquillian.org/)
 and [Cargo](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Home.html) 
to deploy applications into java servers and perform tests on them. -- You can use [tools and services for continuous integration](https://github.com/ligurio/Continuous-Integration-services/blob/master/continuous-integration-services-list.md) such as [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/), [GitLab](https://ci.gitlab.org/), [CircleCi](https://circleci.com/) and [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/) to execute the tests each time a feature is pushed into a git repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...is if there is a way to automatize this process by configuring the pom
>   file, or using a plugin or even implementing our own plugin to do this
>   steps with a single command

You shouldn't need to create or use more plugins for this. It sounds like you already have your pom configured to execute unit and integration tests, which should be sufficient for an automated build.

Take a look at choosing a continuous integration tool (Jenkins, Travis CI, Gitlab CI, etc.) if you're not already. You can configure these tools to run a job automatically whenever code is checked-in (or pushed, PR merged, etc). That job will run whatever Maven command you need, and will handle building, testing, deploying artifacts, without **any** manual interaction.

I seriously question why you need to specify a specific test ID and have manual testing done of a WAR. Sounds like you need to reconsider your testing strategy. **What are you attempting to test that cannot be an automated integration test?** If your answer is specific workflows, or use-cases, it sounds like you need a more comprehensive integration test suite. Also, if everything is automated, there's no reason to not always run a full suite of testing instead of specifying individual tests to run.

---

Edit based on question edit:

> We are a small startup with our product in early to mid stages. Only
>   now we are focusing on test automation, so we have almost none of it,
>   not even basic unit tests. For this reason, all of our tests are made
>   in a exploratory way, skipping the unit and integration tests, until
>   we implement it

Yikes. Good testing should be one of your highest development priorities. It's far too easy to put it off, and then never get around to doing proper testing until it's too late and your consumers/customers encounter serious defects. Make the time investment to write good tests **now**!